# how to print most number of duplicates in php array

Tags: php

May i know how to print most number of duplicates in php array??

let me explain what i exactly wants..

for example i have an array like

```
$fruit = array( ' orange ' , ' banana ' , ' apples ' , ' orange ' , ' banana ', ' banana ' , ' strawberry ', ' apples ');
```

here the array has 3 times of banana, 2 times of orange, apples and 1 time of strawberry..

my problem is i wanna display top 3 most number of repeated data first..

I wanna display like below.

output :

```
    banana
    apples
    orange
```

if apple repeated 4 times in an array means apple comes first place then banana and orange...

Can anyone tell me how to do this using php???

Comment: Does `array_count_values` help?

Comment: `array_count_values -> arsort -> loop keys`

Comment: @Ruban Kutty, Please check my answer. I think It will resolve your problem. I have explained with your example. Let me know if any comments.

Answer (score 1):

**array_count_values**

> Returns an associative array of values from array as keys and their
>   count as value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

and

**asort**

> asort — Sort an array and maintain index association
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 0):

use below code to count array repeat item count

```
$vals = array_count_values($fruit);
arsort($vals);// sort descending order
```

It returns

```
Array
(
    [banana ] => 3
    [apples ] => 2
    [orange ] => 2
    [strawberry ] => 1
)
```